# UNION SELECT after fetch and offset

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure:

```
@offset INT,
@fetch INT

SELECT col1 AS col FROM tab1
UNION
SELECT col1 FROM tab2
ORDER BY col OFFSET @offset ROWS FETCH NEXT @fetch ROWS ONLY
```

Now I want to add a third table as UNION, after the offset and fetch has been executed. Is that possible?

```
UNION
SELECT TOP 1 col1 FROM tab3
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@offset INT,
@fetch INT

WITH CTE1
AS
(SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT col1 AS col FROM tab1
UNION
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT col1 FROM tab2
ORDER BY col OFFSET @offset ROWS FETCH NEXT @fetch ROWS ONLY)

SELECT * FROM CTE1
UNION
SELECT TOP 1 col1 FROM tab3
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Answer (score 2):

use derived table

```
Select col from
(
SELECT col1 AS col FROM tab1
UNION
SELECT col1 FROM tab2
ORDER BY col OFFSET @offset ROWS FETCH NEXT @fetch ROWS ONLY
) a
UNION
SELECT TOP 1 col1 FROM tab3
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

**Note :** You can replace `UNION` with `UNION ALL` if you aren't looking for removing duplicates in result.